# Block posts turns all block to classic block after migration

Tags: wordpress, debugging

With a bit of context I'm working with a WordPress site. I recently migrated a staging site to the live instance of the site and it caused something weird. All the posts currently on the site got turned into a big classic block. The site has been using Gutenberg for over a year now. The site has no classic block plugin. I’ve checked the usual issue like plugin conflicts, and user errors… I also noticed that when checking the post-revision history, there’s a change made by unknown users with a blank name and ones made under my name. However, I’ve never made changes to the specific posts myself.

Anybody know what possible reason for this to happen? my php version is 7.4.33 and WP version is 6.1.2

Basic diagnosis, debug mode, turn off and on all plugins

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.